# jQuery detect element resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to do detect element resize with jquery resize plugin (http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/) on jquery 1.10.2.

```
$("#element").resize(function(){
  console.log("resize");
});
```

I did the testing on Firefox 25 and I get this error:

```
Error: TypeError: r is undefined
Source File: jquery.ba-resize.min.js
Line: 9
```

How can I solve it? Is there any alternative way / plugin for doing this?

Thank you.

Comment: Just remove that plug-in ! , and you will done with it

Answer (score -3, accepted):

**Remove that plug-in**, jQuery done with it self.

```
var element = $('#element');
var current_size = element.width()+'x'+element.height();
element.resize(function(){ 
    var this_size = $(this).width()+'x'+$(this).height();
    if(current_size!==this_size){
      console.log('changed');
      current_size = this_size;
    }
});
```

*PS : Doesn't test*

Comment: maybe you have to use `Mousedown()`, `Mouseup()` ? @user1995781

Comment: I don't understand this answer.

Answer (score 4):

You need a resize sensor which is bundled with css-element-queries of https://github.com/marcj/css-element-queries.

```
new ResizeSensor($('.elements'), function(){
    console.log('resize')
});
```

jQuery's `.resize` only works on `window` object since only `window` has a event `onresize`. All other element haven't and thus you need a polyfill for that. I've seen a lot of other jQuery plugins that allow you to listen on resize changes of all element types, but take care: These are incredible slow as they use `setTimeout()` or interval to check it's dimension change instead of setting up a real resize sensor like the one you can find in the link above.

Comment: I don't understand how can you listen for resize without a `setTimeout()` or a `requestAnimationFrame()`, in fact your code seems to use it... What did I miss? https://github.com/marcj/css-element-queries/blob/93626d81fd9c0f14adbe1bcf82a06e7beaaafbdb/src/ResizeSensor.js#L13

Comment: This animation frame or setTimeout is for something different. It is used to smooth all those event callback calls. Usually an browser can faster render than 60fps, but if you attached a resize listener to an animated div you get  a ton of events called. To reduce those events to max 1 callback per frame helps to save cpu time. It has nothing to do with an slow resize detection, rather the exact opposite: it helps to slow down the very fast resize detection using the `onscroll` events hack.

Comment: Oh, that makes totally sense. :) Thank you for sharing your hack, looks like the internet relies on it.

Answer (score 0):

Using Clay.js (https://github.com/zzarcon/clay) it's quite simple to detect changes on element size:

```
var el = new Clay('.element');

el.on('resize', function(size) {
   console.log(size.height, size.width);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

DIV does not fire a resize event, so you won't be able to do exactly what you've coded, but you could look into monitoring DOM properties.

If you are actually working with something like resizables, and that is the only way for a div to change in size, then your resize plugin will probably be implementing a callback of its own.